# Delete uploaded ffile from both public dir and database

Tags: php, laravel, delete-file

I am trying to delete an uploaded picture from both public directory and database. How do I do that?

I only manage to delete from public dir but I have no idea how to delete from database. Can someone tell me what should I do thanks a lot

Here is the controller I used to remove the picture from public dir:

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
        $image = DB::table('user_images')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $file= $image->name;
        $filename = public_path().'/images/'.$file;
        \File::delete($filename);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`delete()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#deletes) method:

```
$image = DB::table('user_images')->where('id', $id)->first();
$file= $image->name;
$filename = public_path().'/images/'.$file;
\File::delete($filename);
DB::table('user_images')->where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Or [`destroy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#deleting-models):

```
UserImage::destroy($id);
```

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::delete() this is return, do I have to put something in the controller to use the delete method?

Comment: Yup exactly what I wanted. Thank you :)

Comment: Just checking if I used my user_id instead of id how can I do it?

Comment: @Dkna if you'll use `user_id`, it will delete all the rows where `user_id = $id`

Comment: I tried doing something like, $image = DB::table('user_images')->where('user_id', $id)->first();
,but it return me this, Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @Dkna this line of code will return you just one image that belongs to the user (the first one). Do you want to delete all user's images?

Comment: Ohh ok I understand what you meant, so is it something like this? DB::table('user_images')->where('user_id', $id)->delete();. But it just delete the image in public dir and not in database

Comment: @Dkna yes, the code is correct. But it will delete images from DB, not files. So, you need to get a list of files first, iterate over results and delete files one by one.

Comment: Ohh I see thank you very much for answering my question

Answer (score 1):

```
public function destroy($id)
{
        $image = DB::table('user_images')->where('id', $id);

        if($image){

          $file= $image->first()->name;
          $filename = public_path().'/images/'.$file;
          \File::delete($filename);
           $image->delete();
         }

         //Silent fail. Silence is golden.

 }
```

Comment: Hi same question,  Call to undefined method stdClass::delete() this is return, do I have to put something in the controller to use the delete method?

Comment: @Dkna check it again !

Comment: Just a question, if I used user_id instead of id how can I do that?

Comment: it will return images for that specific user. @Dkna.

Comment: But it return me Trying to get property of non-object, when I use user_id instead of id

Comment: if you are using the code from above. ` $image = DB::table('user_images')->where('user_images.user_id', $id);`